# EF 6 - Inject where clause

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to universally add a where clause to all queries that EF is running? I want all queries to run with "entity.Active == true" for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way (without implementing QueryTranslator interface) is to create extension method for your context like this

```
public static IQyertable<YourEntity> OnlyActiveEntities(this YourDbContext context, Action<DbSet<YourEntity>> setConfigurator = null)
{
    var dbSet = context.Set<YourEntity>();
    setConfigurator?.Invoke(dbSet); 

    return context.Set<YourEntity>().AsQueriable().Where(entity => entity.Active == true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some third party library allows filtering queries: [Entity Framework Filter Library List](http://entityframework.net/filter)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Wiki: EF+ Query Filter

This feature is exactly what you are looking for. You can add a global filter for filtering all queries.

Example:

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

QueryFilterManager.Filter<ISoftDelete>(q => q.Where(x => x.IsActive));
```